# How to execute each row without copy pasting the results to another window

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first post, I've been trying to create a script that could execute everything in one run but to no avail, maybe somebody could help

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @user_name    SYSNAME, @login_name SYSNAME;

SELECT @user_name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',@login_name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' SELECT 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ';

        CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@user_name) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@login_name) + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
    EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'',''' + @user_name + '''; GO'

FROM   sys.databases WHERE  state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```

I've tried putting the result in a temp table but had problems in retrieving each row and executing them.

Comment: Use a `CURSOR` and `sp_executesql`. (+1 for using `QUOTENAME`)

Answer (score 0):

you could create a cursor, and loop thru it executing each command
example:

```
set nocount on

declare @user_name    SYSNAME, @login_name SYSNAME
declare @command1 varchar(4000)
declare @command2 varchar(4000)

select @user_name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', @login_name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' 

declare crCommands cursor local FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY for 
  select 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ' CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@user_name) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@login_name) + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]',
         'EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'',''' + @user_name + ''''
  from   sys.databases 
  where  state_desc = 'ONLINE'

open crCommands
fetch next from crCommands into @command1, @command2 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
     exec sp_executesql @command1
     exec sp_executesql @command2
     fetch next from crCommands  into @command1, @command2
end
close crCommands
deallocate crCommands
```

This might need some changes to comply with what you need but it should be able to get you on your way

Answer (score -1):

Try using BEGIN END statement as follows : -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @user_name    SYSNAME, @login_name SYSNAME;

SELECT @user_name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM',@login_name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' SELECT 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ';

BEGIN CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@user_name) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@login_name) + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'',''' + @user_name + '''; END'
FROM   sys.databases WHERE  state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```

Comment: How will that help the OP avoiding what they're doing at the moment; Copying and Pasting?